# Hosting Java Code On a Website (No application)

Tags: java

recently I have been making easy games such as 'blackjack' , quizzes, etc. How do I host these games online so others can play? Keep in mind these games do not use an application. Thank you

Comment: Have you looked into applets? There is no need for a specialized JSP server though that may be convenient for your future work in Java and web.

Comment: Consider switching to Javascript.

Comment: most people disable java on their browsers. Forget that, use regular HTML + javascript.

Comment: @HighCore: Yep, together with CSS.

Comment: @hovercraftfullofeels yeah, I forgot :P

Answer (score 1):

If your application is Swing/AWT based - and if you implement the game as a Component or JComponent - you can then, with minimal changes, make it run as both a Swing/AWT (i.e. desktop) application or as an Applet (embedded in a web page).  You can make both run from the same .jar file, if you set it up right, and that file can also contain you resources (images, sounds).  (It doesn't have too - but they you may need to load these resource in a somewhat different way, depending whether you are running as an application or applet.)

For the desktop, place you game component into a JFrame and display this (with appropriate sizing, etc).

For the web, place the component into an Applet.  You will need a bunch of configuration and an HTML page with the applet in it.  But once you have this you can host you game on any ordinary ISP site.

This may be a bit out of date, but: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/

Comment: I should add that plenty of sites (companies, etc) block applets from running.  And it may find you need to tweak the set up (e.g. the way you embedded the applet in the page) to make it work on different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into Ruby on Rails for back end develoment: http://rubyonrails.org/
and Javascript for front end development: http://www.w3schools.com/js/

http://www.codecademy.com/ also has great lesson plans for building online games.